# Mi función se ejecuta dos veces javascript

Tags: javascript, http

Hola muy buenas tardes a todos, tengo un problema pasa que  mi función
se ejecuta dos veces en la consola de google me muestra dos veces los datos
y cuando quiero llamar datos individuales me muestra el dato y un undefined, lo que quiero buscar es como puedo hacer que solo se ejecute una sola vez, ya que al consultar los datos solo me los muestra vacíos o me los muestra doble.

mi código es este:

```
<script >
 var cp = "";
   const funcionInit = () => {
if (!"geolocation" in navigator) {
    return alert("Tu navegador no soporta el acceso a la ubicación. Intenta con otro");
}

const $latitud = document.querySelector("#latitud"),
    $longitud = document.querySelector("#longitud")


 onUbicacionConcedida = ubicacion => {
    
    var $estandarlongitud = 0;
    var estandarlatitud = 0;

    const coordenadas = ubicacion.coords;
    $latitud.innerText = coordenadas.latitude;
    $longitud.innerText = coordenadas.longitude;
    $estandarlongitud = parseInt($longitud.innerText);
    estandarlatitud = parseInt($latitud.innerText);
    /*console.log(estandarlatitud,$estandarlongitud);
    console.log("las coordenadas son:", $latitud.innerText,$longitud.innerText);*/
    $("#latitudinput").val(coordenadas.latitude);
    $("#longitudinput").val(coordenadas.longitude);
    var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https://api.mymappi.com/v2/geocoding/reverse?apikey=8cec55ea-407d-4228-9bd4- 
    9eb08585b116&lat=' + coordenadas.latitude + '&lon=' +coordenadas.longitude;

  Http.open('GET', url);
  Http.send();
  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {


  let objRest =JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
  console.log("colonia es: ",objRest.data.address.suburb);
 console.log("codigo postal es",objRest.data.address.postcode);
 console.log(objRest);
 $("#codigopostal").val(objRest.data.address.postcode);
 console.log($("#codigopostal").val())
 cp = objRest.data.address.postcode;
 }
  }
    const onErrorDeUbicacion = err => {

    $latitud.innerText = "Error obteniendo ubicación: " + err.message;
    $longitud.innerText = "Error obteniendo ubicación: " + err.message;
    console.log("Error obteniendo ubicación: ", err);
}

const opcionesDeSolicitud = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true, // Alta precisión
    maximumAge: 0, // No queremos caché
    timeout: 5000 // Esperar solo 5 segundos
};

$latitud.innerText = "Cargando...";
$longitud.innerText = "Cargando...";
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onUbicacionConcedida, onErrorDeUbicacion, 
  opcionesDeSolicitud);

};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funcionInit);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que la función completa se ejecute dos veces, el problema está en la petición AJAX, que no estás analizando el cambio de estado para saber si la petición inició o terminó.

Deberías ejecutar esas instrucciones solo si la [petición finalizó con éxito](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readystatechange_event#example):

```
Http.open('GET', url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    // ¿Terminó exitosamente?
    if(Http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && Http.status === 200) {
        let objRest =JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
        console.log("colonia es: ",objRest.data.address.suburb);
        console.log("codigo postal es",objRest.data.address.postcode);
        console.log(objRest);
        $("#codigopostal").val(objRest.data.address.postcode);
        console.log($("#codigopostal").val())
        cp = objRest.data.address.postcode;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me funciono perfectamente, saludos